# What notation to use for a sequence of integers that end with digit 5?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, notation

I need to solve a low high school home work and I ask a question about the most correct notation. The problem is to build a set of circles with $r$ and $d$ such that $d=5, 15, 25, 35,...d_{+_1}$ and so on. All values of $d$ should be ended by $5.$ What is the best notation for that and how to formulated as $d(mod)5.$ Sorry for the weak question and thank you for your help. My brother wrote the question for me.

Comment: (re: votes to close) I think this is a reasonable question: the homework was about more than just these numbers, and the OP asked only about one specific aspect of it, what notation to use.

Answer (score 3):

Using a subscript notation, you can say the values of $d$ come from the series $d_1, d_2, d_3, \ldots$, where $d_n = 10n - 5$.